# Shortest way to print year in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

Can somebody tell me the shortest way to print the current year in Node.js? I'm looking to print current year in footer with Copyright notice.

I understand I can do this using JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
```

But this is a client-side dependent solution. I'm more looking for a server-side solution.

Can anybody help, please?

Regards,
Bill

Comment: Do you use view template?

Comment: Yes, I'm using EJS as template engine!

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you wouldn't want to use the client's date?

Comment: For me, the copyright year should come from the server. If the client's device's date on 1994, that will show 1994 on copyright :)

Comment: If about Copyright notice, I think that should be a hard string "2019", "1994", etc. Why do you want the Copyright year like a variable in stead of a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data to your EJS template by using `res.render()`

On Server:

```
res.render('yourTemplate', {
    year: new Date().getFullYear(),
});
```

On `EJS` Template

```
<div>
    <%= year %>
</div>
```